# Vertically style table using CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have the following table:

**html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>water<br /><br /></td>
        <td>oil</td>
        <td>fire</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>spec1<br /><br /></td>
        <td>spec2</td>
        <td>spec3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css:**

```
table th, td {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:10px;
}
```

How can I make it so the table looks like this: (I can only use CSS or jQuery to manipulate it)

```
water   spec1 
oil     spec2 
fire    spec3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HAQ3s/30/

Comment: http://whathaveyourtried.com?

Comment: Ihavetriedthis.com! - http://jsfiddle.net/HAQ3s/33/
I basically took the other guys suggestion, did display block to the td and then added some jquery to add a class to the 2nd tr block, then i can position it with CSS but its not working.

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support?

Comment: all browsers, do you know how to add a class to the 2nd tr in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
td {
 display: block;   
}
```

And then, after having given an id to each td :

```
​#t1:before {
    content:"water";
}​​​​​
```

After that, you can "remove" the br with negative margin :

```
#t2 {
   margin-top:-15px;   
}
```

Last trick is to add spacing to compensate for different lengths of labels : use the unicode \00A0 in content.

```
#t2:before {
    content:"oil \00A0\00A0\00A0\00A0\00A0";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/BNLgH/

EDIT : if you can generate the html, simply do this :

```
<table>
<tr><td align=right>water</td><td>0</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: OK... so you still may use what I propose but why don't you simply generate a table with 3 rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/HAQ3s/34/). It tests correctly in FF. Haven't tried other browsers.

I added the block and inline-block statements below to your original style.

CSS:

```
table th, td {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:10px;
    display:block;
}
table tr
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
}
```

You can use negative margins in the `table tr` style definition to adjust spacing to taste.